# How do I get KPIs within an enterprise environment?

Tags: enterprise

Yesterday I had a telephone conference with a business analyst telling me, that any hedonic feature within our enterprise product will only be considered by our stakeholders if they are convinced with meaningful business goals.

We have many existing user journeys in our product that fulfill nearly all pragmatic and functional needs. But these are in dare need of a revamp in sense of making the users feel connected, giving them a sense of expertise or making them feel independently. How can I track, measure or come up with any KPI that would underline building hedonic features for our users and not building new functional needs only for the buyers/stakeholders?

I guess my main problem is how to get those indicators within an enterprise environment.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have buy-in from stakeholders and align with their business goals you need to **"speak their language"** by highlighting the obvious return on investment that they will achieve if they adopt a more user centred approach.

> I guess my main problem is how to get those indicators within an
>   enterprise environment.

I think the Kano model offers a great way of linking and aligning UX best practices with business goals and objectives:

> The Kano Model of Customer satisfaction (Figure 1) divides product
>   attributes into three categories: threshold, performance, and
>   excitement. A competitive product meets basic attributes, maximises
>   performances attributes, and includes as many “excitement” attributes
>   as possible at a cost the market can bear.

How the [**Kano Model**](http://people.ucalgary.ca/~design/engg251/First%20Year%20Files/kano.pdf) works:

[image]

Enterprise environments generally suffer from [**feature creep**](http://blog.intercom.io/what-does-feature-creep-look-like/) and function over form mentality:

> Most enterprise clients have their own procurement procedures and
>   project management techniques that don’t jive with a healthy UX
>   workflow. Designers often find themselves needing to shoehorn their
>   process into an existing structure, an exercise which can be
>   frustrating if not approached properly.

To answer your question directly I would say: **Find a way of integrating the Kano model approach into the development process so the ROI is clearly visible. This will help boost adoption rates for existing features and help weed-out any new unnecessary features or functionalities.**

Hope this helps

Comment: Good answer. I've never heard of the Kano model, thanks for making me aware of it.

Comment: Note: to fight feature creep, you may use the "Usage Index" as KPI (see the book [THE PROFESSIONAL PRODUCT OWNER](https://theprofessionalproductowner.org/).